# Getting "This action would increase the number of cells in the worksheet above the limit of 2000000 cells" when calling Sheet API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Sheets V4 [append API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) to insert data into a newly created sheet. I am inserting data with 1000 rows and 1001 columns i.e 1001000 cells.

```
String url = https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<spreadSheetId>/values/<workSheetName>!A1:append?access_token=<accessToken>&valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS
    //CREATING THE REQUEST BODY
reqBody.put("range", <workSheetName>+"!A1");
reqBody.put("majorDimension", "ROWS");
reqBody.put("values", <values>);
```

I am getting `400 Bad Request` with the message :

> This action would increase the number of cells in the worksheet above the limit of 2000000 cells

I know that Google has 2 million cells per sheet limit, but I'm unable to find out why I'm getting this exception especially since I have not exceeded the limit.

Any help on why this error may occur?

Comment: None. I create the sheet and then insert the values. Still get this error.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this problem?

Comment: No this error still occurs in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Google seemingly counts cells that are are already there, **even if they're blank**, **even in a brand new spreadsheets**. The solution is to wipe those columns first.  Manually you'd do it by selecting a column, right clicking, and choosing Delete.

Using the API, you need [deleteDimension](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest) - here's a PHP example:

```
        new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
          "deleteDimension" => [
            "range" => [
              "sheetId" => $sheetId,
              "dimension" => "COLUMNS",
              "startIndex" => 1,
              "endIndex" => 26
              ],
          ],
        ]);
```

Notes:

- Google has unusual syntax for indicating ranges - the first column *does* start at 0, but the end column needs to be the one *after* you want, so 0-1 is column A, not A and B.
- In this example, we delete all but the first column - it won't let you delete the entire sheet, e.g. if you were to do 0-26 (i.e. all of them) you'd get:

> Invalid requests[1].deleteDimension: You can't delete all the columns on the sheet.

- don't worry, although you now only have a single column, as many new columns as you need will be added automatically when you add data
- The workbook limit I get in Dec 2019 is 5,000,000, not 2,000,000:

> Invalid requests[2].pasteData: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells.